# A problem relative to the Cameron-Martin Theorem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

If We denote by $\mathbb{L}_{0}$ the law of standard Brownian motion $\lbrace B(t):t \in [0,1] \rbrace$, and for a function $F:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ write $\mathbb{L}_{F}$ for the law of $$\lbrace B(t)+F(t):t \in [0,1] \rbrace.$$ I am trying to prove a necessary condition for functions $F$ any set $A$ with $\mathbb{L}_{0}(A)=0$ also satisfies $\mathbb{L}_{F}(A)=0$. Morters and Peres claim that if such function $F$ exists, then it must be a continuous function with $F(0)=0$. I don't know where to start. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Use the hypothesis with $A:=\{\psi:[0,1) \to {\mathbb R}  :\psi(0)\ne 0\}$
and then with $A:=\{\psi:[0,1) \to {\mathbb R}  : \quad \psi \; \, \text{has a point of discontinuity} \}$.